# Algorithm for drawing a 4-connected line

Tags: graphics, line, bresenham

I'm looking for an algorithm (coded in Java would be nice, but anything clear enough to translate to Java is fine) to draw a 4-connected line. It seems that [Bresenham's algorithm](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/drawing-line-using-bresenham-algorithm/) is the most widely used, but all the understandable implementations I've found are 8-connected. OpenCV's [cvline](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/drawing_functions.html#cv-line) function apparently has a 4-connected version, but the source code is, to me, as a mediocre and nearly C-illiterate programmer, impenetrable. Various other searches have turned up nothing.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Here's the source for [cvline](http://opencv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.0-6.1/cxdrawing_8cpp-source.html). I couldn't add it in the original post due to the new user limit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is a Bresenham-like algorithm that draws 4-connected lines. The code is in Python but I suppose can be understood easily even if you don't know the language.

```py
def line(x0, y0, x1, y1, color):
    dx = abs(x1 - x0)    # distance to travel in X
    dy = abs(y1 - y0)    # distance to travel in Y

    if x0 < x1:
        ix = 1           # x will increase at each step
    else:
        ix = -1          # x will decrease at each step

    if y0 < y1:
        iy = 1           # y will increase at each step
    else:
        iy = -1          # y will decrease at each step

    e = 0                # Current error 

    for i in range(dx + dy):
        draw_pixel(x0, y0, color)
        e1 = e + dy
        e2 = e - dx
        if abs(e1) < abs(e2):
            # Error will be smaller moving on X
            x0 += ix
            e = e1
        else:
            # Error will be smaller moving on Y
            y0 += iy
            e = e2
```

The idea is that to draw a line you should increment X and Y with a ratio that matches DX/DY of the theoretic line. To do this I start with an **error** variable `e` initialized to 0 (we're on the line) and at each step I check if the error is lower if I only increment X or if I only increment Y (Bresenham check is to choose between changing only X or both X and Y).

The naive version for doing this check would be adding `1/dy` or `1/dx`, but multiplying all increments by `dx*dy` allows using only integer values and that improves both speed and accuracy and also avoids the need of special cases for `dx==0` or `dy==0` thus simplifying the logic.
Of course since we're looking for a proportion error, using a scaled increment doesn't affect the result.

Whatever is the line quadrant the two possibilities for the increment will always have a different sign effect on the error... so my arbitrary choice was to increment the error for an X step and decrement the error for an Y step.

The `ix` and `iy` variables are the real directions needed for the line (either +1 or -1) depending on whether the initial coordinates are lower or higher than the final coordinates.

The number of pixels to draw in a 4-connected line is obviously `dx+dy`, so I just do a loop for that many times to draw the line instead of checking if I got to the end point. Note that this algorithm draws all pixels except the last one; if you want also that final pixel then an extra `draw_pixel` call should be added after the end of the loop.

An example result of the above implementation can be seen in the following picture

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the long acceptance time, got caught up in something else. I'll post a Java version once I code it.

Answer (score 7):

For the Python-illiterate, here is a C version of 6502's code:

```
void drawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    int dx = abs(x1 - x0);
    int dy = abs(y1 - y0);
    int sgnX = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
    int sgnY = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
    int e = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < dx+dy; i++) {
        drawPixel(x0, y0);
        int e1 = e + dy;
        int e2 = e - dx;
        if (abs(e1) < abs(e2)) {
            x0 += sgnX;
            e = e1;
        } else {
            y0 += sgnY;
            e = e2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The digital straight line that connects fractional coordinates might be different than that connecting integer coordinates.
For an example, consider the image below which shows the 4-connected digital straight lines between the points (1, 1) - (6, 3), (1, 0.6) - (6, 2.6), and (1, 1.4) - (6, 3.4).

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSgvy.png)

While all start points and end points lie on the pixels (1, 1) and (6, 4) the digital straigt 4-connected lines are different.

The code below computes the 4-connected digital straight line between a fractional start and end point.
Actually, the code works also for n dimensions and computes the 2n-connected digital straight line.

```py
import numpy as np

def points_on_line(start, end):

    idx = np.round(np.array(start)).astype(int)
    end_idx = np.round(np.array(end)).astype(int)
    points = [idx]

    if np.all(idx == end_idx):
        return points

    diff = np.array(end, dtype=float) - np.array(start, dtype=float)
    direction = (diff / np.abs(diff)).astype(int)
    coord = np.array(start, dtype=float)

    while np.any(idx != end_idx):
        # compute how far we need to go to reach the side of the pixel at idx
        t = (idx + direction / 2 - coord) / diff
        i = np.argmin(t)
        coord += t[i] * diff
        idx = idx.copy()
        idx[i] += direction[i]
        points.append(idx)

    return points
```