# How do I select a set of grid cells along a given angle quickly?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, grid, tiles

I have set up a grid class that contains theoretical cells.

I have a method `collectCells()` which accepts a starting point, radians and distance as arguments. I want this method to return an Array containing all the cells that are along a given angle and that are within the specified distance from the starting point, e.g.

[image]

The easiest way for me to do this is just loop through all the pixels in the given direction and pick cells up as I go, something like:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<distance; i++)
{
    startPoint.x += Math.cos(radians);
    startPoint.y += Math.sin(radians);

    if( start point falls within uncollected cell) collect cell;
}
```

This is obviously really poor, as the loop will be as long as the distance I specify - extremely slow.

I tried something different, creating a `nextCell()` method which accepts the last collected cell and radians. The method threw a point 25 pixels in the direction specified by radians, collected the resulting cell and then started over from that cell for a given amount of cells.

I didn't really think about this approach clearly enough, and once done realized that I had a problem, being that the actual path I'm testing gets broken each time the next cell is sought, e.g.

[image]

Where the green dotted line is the desired path, and the blue lines are the paths that make up each `nextCell()` call because the check is made from the centre of each cell.

What is the correct way to efficiently collect the cells in a given direction over a specified distance (pixels)?

Comment: Your method will not be that slow if you do not compute `sin` and `cos` at each iteration. Anyway, what you are looking for is called a [4-connected line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5186939/111461)

Comment: @SamHocevar Good point, I'll move that outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). Because literally you are trying to draw a pixel width line but with huge pixels.

Comment: Note that by default Bresenham draws 8-connected lines, but the asker describes a 4-connected line.